# Angular 2 Webpack - export * from './some-folder' no longer works?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I am using angular-cli@webpack.

I am using barrels, so for example my shared folder has something like this in its index.ts:

`export * from './header';`

However, that worked fine with systemjs.  Now, it doesn't work.  It does work if I do `export { HeaderComponent } from './header';`.

Can someone help me out?  Why this change, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Isn't it import * as name from "./header"?

Comment: no.  i was using angular-cli 10 with system js which would make the barrel for me.

Comment: Yes but now you are using webpack and webpack bundle your files and make something else. That can be the issue. Try to give a name to your import and see if it work..